# Increment index in for loop only if condition met

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python and run into a bit of a snag. I'm building a simple to-do list, and I've built it out to display a list only if the first character is a ❌. This works, but when an item is marked complete (with a ✅), it still counts increments the index on the code below.

I assumed that `index += 1` inside an if statement would only increment the index if the condition is met - is this not the case?

```
def read_list():
read_list = open("todo.txt","r", encoding='utf-8')
for index, item in enumerate(read_list, 1):
    item = item.rstrip('\n')
    if item[0] == '❌':
        print(f'{index}. {item}')
        index += 1
```

The current output of this is:

```
1. ❌ TASK 1
3. ❌ TASK 2
```

This is because the second item on the list is '✅ TASK 3'

Comment: If you're checking the first character, why `rstrip` before the check? It's potentially wasted energy. It's more efficient to only strip when you know you'll be printing the item.

Comment: You may also want to set a width specifier on your `index` in the f-string, depending on how many items there might be, to ensure proper alignment. `print(f"{index:3}. {item.rstrip()}")`

Comment: The purpose of the rstrip was to remove the line break when printing multiple items. When I put the rstrip directly into the f string, it would error. Is there something I'm missing there? Wouldn't the f string then be looking for a variable called item.rstrip()?

Comment: You don't need to put a variable name into an f-string. Just an _expression_ which `item.rstrip()` is. Of course, an expression can include a variable name.

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash` when I try to do this. `print(f"{numTasks}. {item.rstrip('\n')} - ({index})")`. Can you not include the actual linebreak removal within the fstring?

Comment: Exactly. You can do `f"{item.rstrip()}"` though. This will remove any trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for index, item in ...` already increments `index`. On your first loop, you are printing (current index 1) then adding (current index 1) + 1 which is 2 then increments + 1 with `for loop`. So in your second loop, it prints 3.

Create a separate variable outside of the for loop:

```py
numTasksIncomplete = 0
for index, item in enumerate(read_list, 1):
    item = item.rstrip('\n')
    if item[0] == '❌':
        print(f'{index}. {item}')
        numTasksIncomplete += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the purpose of variable `index` you are trying to increment.

Currently, `index` and `item` and assigned new values every time the loop iterates over `read_list`. `index` and `task` in the for loop with enumerate basically resolves to getting the index and value from `read_list` one by one.

You are trying to increase the same variable `index` inside `if` condition.

Even if you increment it, next time the loop runs, it will overwrite the value.

If you are trying to count the number of tasks that are incomplete, you can use a new variable and name it different that one you are using in the `for` loop.

Try this :

```
incomplete_count = 0
for index, item in enumerate(read_list, 1):
    item = item.rstrip('\n')
    if item[0] == '❌':
        print(f'{index}. {item}')
        incomplete_count += 1
```